# Java Selling Tickets with Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have two threads to sell tickets.

```
public class MyThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(()->{
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                ticket.sell();
            } }, "A");

        thread1.start();
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(()->{
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                ticket.sell();
            } }, "B");
        thread2.start();

    }

}

class Ticket {

    private Integer num = 20 ;

    private Object obj = new Object();

    public void sell() {

        // why shouldn't I use "num" as a monitor object ?
        // I thought "num" is unique among two threads.
        synchronized ( num ) { 

            if (this.num >= 0) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " sells " + this.num + "th ticket");
                this.num--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be wrong if I use `num` as a monitor object.

But if I use `obj` as a monitor object, the output will be correct.

What's the difference between using `num` and using `obj` ?

===============================================

And why does it still not work if I use `(Object)num` as a monitor object ?

```
class Ticket {

    private int num = 20 ;

    private Object obj = new Object();

    public void sell() {
        
        // Can I use (Object)num as a monitor object ?
        synchronized ( (Object)num ) { 

            if (this.num >= 0) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " sells " + this.num + "th ticket");
                this.num--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Integer is immutable, so `num--` is shorthand for `num = new Integer(num - 1)`, so you won't always be synchronising on the same object.

Comment: @tgdavies not quite: `num = Integer.valueOf(num.intValue() - 1);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is [*synchronizing on a non-final value*](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/SynchronizeOnNonFinalFieldhttp://errorprone.info/bugpattern/SynchronizeOnNonFinalField).

The most important thing to understand about the Java Memory Model - that is, what values a thread sees whilst executing a Java program - is the [*happens-before* relationship](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html).

In the specific case of a synchronized block, actions done in one thread before exiting the synchronized block *happen before* actions done inside the synchronized block in another thread - so, if the first thread increments a variable inside that synchronized block, the second thread sees that updated value.

This goes over and above the well-known fact that a synchronized block can only be entered by one thread at a time: only one thread at a time *and* you get to see what the previous thread did.

```
// Thread 1                   // Thread 2
synchronized (monitor) {
  num = 1
}                   // Exiting monitor
                    // *happens before*
                    // entering monitor
                              synchronized (monitor) {
                                int n = num;  // Guaranteed to see n = 1 (provided no other thread has entered a block synchronized on monitor and changed it first).
                              }
```

There is a very important caveat to this guarantee: it only holds if the two executions of the synchronized block use **the same monitor**. And that's not the same *variable*, it's the same actual concrete object on the heap (variables don't have monitors, they're just pointers to a value in the heap).

So, if you reassign the monitor inside the synchronized block:

```
synchronized (num) {
  if (num > 0) {
    num--;  // This is the same as `num = Integer.valueOf(num.intValue() - 1);`
  }
}
```

then you are **destroying the happens-before guarantee**, because the next thread to arrive at that synchronized block is entering the monitor of a different object (*).

Once you do, the behavior of your program is ill-defined: if you're lucky, it fails in an obvious way; if you're very unlucky, it can *seem* to work, and then start failing mysteriously at a later date.

Your code is just broken.

This isn't something that's specific to `Integer`s either: this code would have the same problem.

```
// Assume `Object someObject = new Object();` is defined as a field.

synchronized (someObject) {
  someObject = new Object();
}
```

---

(*) Actually, you still get a happens-before relationship for the new object: it's just not for the things inside this synchronized block, it's for things that happened in some other synchronized block that used the object as the monitor. Essentially, it's impossible to reason about what this means, so you may as well just consider it "broken".

---

The correct way to do it is to synchronize on a field that you **can't** (not just *don't*) reassign. You could simply synchronize on `this` (which can't be reassigned):

```
synchronized (this) {
  if (num > 0) {
    num--;  // This is the same as `num = Integer.valueOf(num.intValue() - 1);`
  }
}
```

Now it doesn't matter that you're reassigning `num` inside the block, because you're not synchronizing on it any more. You get the happens-before guarantee from the fact that you're always synchronizing on the same thing.

Note, however, that you must *always* access `num` from inside a synchronized block - for example, if you have a getter to get the number of tickets remaining, *that* must also synchronize on `this`, in order to get the happens-before guarantee that the value changed in the `sell()` method is visible in that getter.

---

This works, but it may not be entirely desirable: anybody who has access to a reference to your `Ticket` instance can also synchronize on it. This means they can potentially deadlock your code.

Instead, it is a common practice to introduce a private field which is used purely for locking: this is what the `obj` field gives you. The only modification from your code should be to make it `final` (and give it a better name than `obj`):

```
private final Object obj = new Object();
```

This can't be accessed outside your class, so nefarious clients cannot cause a deadlock for you directly.

Again, this can't be reassigned inside your synchronized block (or anywhere else), so there is no risk of you breaking the happens-before guarantee by reassigning it.

Answer (score 3):

`Integer` is a boxed value. It contains a primitive `int`, and the compiler deals with autoboxing/autounboxing that `int`. Because of this, the statement `this.num--` is actually:

```
num=Integer.valueOf(num.intValue()-1)
```

That is, the `num` instance containing the lock is lost once you perform that update.

Comment: Thanks. But if I use ```private int num = 20 ;```, and cast ```num``` to Object as a monitor object ```(Object) num```  . It's still wrong. Why ?

Comment: @burakserdar not quite: `num = Integer.valueOf(num.intValue() - 1);`.

Comment: @dannylin you're not making `num` into an `Object` by casting it, you're just telling the compiler "treat this reference as a reference to an Object". `num` is still concretely an Integer.

Comment: @AndyTurner If I define ```num``` as ```int```, is it still an Integer ?

Comment: @dannylin no, `int` is not the same as `Integer`. `int` is a primitive, and you can't synchronize on primitives for one thing.

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm sorry, but I still don't quite understand. Why can't I use ```num``` as a monitor object if I define ```num``` as ```int```. I understand if I define ```num``` as ```Integer```, the compiler will autounbox it. But if I define ```num``` as ```int```, why does it still not work ?

Comment: @dannylin "why can't I use `num` as a monitor object if I define `num` as `int`" because the language specification [doesn't allow you to](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19): reference types all derive from `Object`, and all `Object`s have their own monitor, so you can synchronize on them; primitive types do not have a monitor, so you can't synchronize on them.

Comment: @AndyTurner If I define another ```int``` like ```private int a = 1 ;```, and use ```(Object) a``` as a monitor object. It seems that it does work(?)

Comment: @dannylin no. That can have exactly the same problem as declaring it as `Integer` (because all `(Object) a` is doing is `(Object) Integer.valueOf(a)`. It is very important to remember with multithreading that "seems to work" is not the same as "guaranteed to work".